# Unable to run script remotely on VIO servers?

Tags: shell, ksh, aix, rsh

I need to run an KSH script in VIO server remotely. But as VIO server is in restricted shell, I tried as below.

```
ssh -q -T padmin@vioserver  "oem_setup_env" < script.ksh
```

This was worked fine last time, But when try again today I found this throwing an error.

```
rksh: oem_setup_env:  not found
```

Can someone suggest how to run remotely on VIO servers.

Comment: I have tried like `ssh -q -T padmin@vioserver "/usr/ios/cli/ioscli oem_setup_env"` now it throwing error as `rksh: /usr/ios/cli/ioscli: restricted` . **Is there any ways to make it work**

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using keys so you can log in without using a password.  If the previous sentence makes no sense to you, we can address that as well.  Just ask.

VIOS is just AIX so it has a root user.  You can find the path of root’s home with `echo ~root`.  As I recall, it is usually /. So, become root by doing the oem_setup_env.  Create ~root/.ssh.  Copy your public key into ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys.  Check all the permissions.  They should be owned by root, and be either 0700 or 0600 permissions (not readable nor writable by others).  Then use `ssh root@host ...`

Comment: No we are not using ssh keys, I have to login through padmin user then need switch to root through oem_setup_env.

Comment: I would suggest learn about ssh keys.  It is very nice and secure.  Then, as mentioned, add a key to root’s authorized file.

Answer (score 1):

I tumbled upon this question when looking for a way to run commands as root through ssh. I found this to work:

```
ssh padmin@vioshost "echo lparstat -i | oem_setup_env"
```

lparstat could be substituted by and commands to be run as root.

Comment: great suggestion!
only problem is: ssh -q -T padmin@vioserver  "oem_setup_env" < script.ksh
and: cat script.ksh | ssh -q -T padmin@vioserver  "oem_setup_env"
should also work, so I wonder what was wrong with the original author's padmin profile